# How do you provide rowHeight to react-window using Ant Design Table

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro, react-window

Anyone has tried using Ant Design Table together with react-window to improve the performance? The problem I ran into is how to calculate the rowHeight and provide it to react-window. Our table support resizing column, so the rowHeight is dynamic.